# Why does this integral resolves to a delta function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\left(p - p'\right)x/\hbar}\,{\rm d}x
=
2\pi\hbar\,\delta\left(p - p'\right)
$$

Found this in my control textbook, I try graphing it using wolfram alpha, which does look like a delta, however I have trouble proving it.

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: It depends on what your definitions are. Strictly speaking left hand side does not converge. However, you can interpret LHS by taking a uniform limit, or as distributions. In both interpretations, you would get the right hand side.

Comment: See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta . Also, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delta function isn't really a function as such, but if one is interested it in the context of applications, you can try and imagine the delta function as a limit of a Gaussian with $\sigma\to0$ and with amplitude such that the integral is always one.

Now calculate the Fourier transform of this function to see what you get. The intuition behind this from a signal analysis perspective is that if you know the frequency exactly (a.k.a a delta function), the time signal is just a constant wave with that frequency.